# Reset dynamically created form fields in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form whose fields are dynamically populated. I want to clear all the fields at once. What is the best and easiest way to do this. For normal static forms I have used $("#form")[0].reset() and it works but it isn't working for dynamic forms.

Comment: Show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

`reset()` restores form fields to the contents of their `value` attribute, regardless of whether that was defined as static HTML or dynamically-created DOM nodes:

```js
$('form').append('<input class="dynamic" value="original dynamic value">');

// note these will behave differently:
$('#two').val("Changed by setting .val()");
$('#three').attr("value","Changed by updating value attribute");
    
$('button').on("click",function() {
   $('form')[0].reset();
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button>reset</button>
  <input id="one" value="original static value">
  <input id="two" value="original static value">
  <input id="three" value="original static value">
</form>
```

If you want to clear the fields, you need to explicitly set them to empty values:

```js
$('form').append('<input class="dynamic" value="original dynamic value">');

$('button').on("click",function() {
   $('form input').val('')
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <button>reset</button>
  <input class="static" value="original static value">
</form>
```

Comment: *reset() returns form fields to their value when initially created* Well, not actually, it returns the form field to whatever its `value` attribute has been set to (if anything), which could be different than what it was initially set to.

Answer (score 0):

The following will reset a form with either static or dynamically added elements

```js
button_reset_dynamic_form.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const FORMS = document.querySelectorAll('form')
  FORMS.forEach((element) => {
    element.reset()
  })
})
button_add_inputs_to_form.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let label = document.createElement('label')
  label.innerText = 'Dynamically Added Input'
  let input = document.createElement('input')
  input.type = 'text'
  dynamic_form.appendChild(label)
  dynamic_form.appendChild(input)
})
```

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.buttons {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<form id="dynamic_form" class="form">
  <div>
    <label>Static Select List</label>
    <select>
      <option value="North America" selected>North America</option>
      <option value="International">International</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="">Static Input</label>
    <input type="text" value="11.11" />
  </div>
</form>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="button_add_inputs_to_form">Dynamically Add Input</button>
  <button id="button_reset_dynamic_form">Reset Dynamic Form</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this `document.getElementById("myForm").reset();`

Comment: `$("#myForm")[0]` and `document.getElementById("myForm")` are the exact same thing, so this is just repeating what's already in the question.